# iOS - Show splash screen every time app opens

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen

I know this is bad UX, however a client has requested that I display a splash screen for 2 seconds every time the user opens the app.

I have tried implementing this through the AppDelegate by:

- Creating an instance variable of the splash screens view controller
  in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, and
  settings the alpha of its view to 0.
- Then in applicationWillEnterForeground: I set the alpha to 1 in the
  hope that the splash screen will show every time the user opens the
  app, then set the alpha back to 0 after 2 seconds.

Now, this does work, however not properly. When the app opens the main UI is shown momentarily then the splash screen is shown.

Of course this is not what is intended as the splash screen should be shown before the main UI.

I am trying to persuade the client to do away with this, however does anyone know how it can be implemented properly (in case they are totally adamant that they want it)?

From application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
_tabBarController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
[[self window] setRootViewController:_tabBarController];
[_tabBarController setDelegate:self];


_loadingViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoadingView"];
[[_loadingViewController view] setAlpha:0.0f];
[_loadingViewController willMoveToParentViewController:_tabBarController];
[_tabBarController addChildViewController:_loadingViewController];
[_loadingViewController didMoveToParentViewController:_tabBarController];
[[_tabBarController view] addSubview:_loadingViewController.view];
```

From applicationWillEnterForeground:

```
[[_loadingViewController view] setAlpha:1.0f];

[self performSelector:@selector(removeLoadingView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

Comment: Well you have the default launch images anyway is this not enough for your client?

Comment: Your app should it return to it's previous state after going to background and returning to active?

Comment: Believe me, I have tried, however they are adamant that they want the user to see the splash screen every time they open the app.

Comment: To be honest you could just show them the Apple Human Interface Guidelines around splashscreens and then the Apple review rules that state that Apps have to abide to these guidelines or they will be rejected because that is totally true. There is your argument to get the client to change there mind if they want it in the actual app store they will not be able to have it, simple. I've had loads of disagreements with clients but as soon as you show them the Apple guidelines they drop it because they want a to appear in the store.

Comment: Also show some code please.

Comment: The problem is they use an iOS app which already does this, and of course want the same.

Comment: I'd still show them the guidelines. Some apps slip through but must don't, if you have a project manager tell them that it's not allowed and let them argue it out with the client all you can do is provide them with the correct information and if they don't like it then bad luck or if your high enough in the food chain just give a simple **NO** it's not happening and shove the Apple guidelines in front of them.

Comment: You can always do it, and then bill them the extra time for removing the "feature" when the app gets rejected. As long as your management adds that to the contract, go ahead. The customer is always right (as long as the customer pays the bill, and then pays another bill when they are proved wrong).

Comment: @gnasher729 My problem is "I can't get it to work" hence my reason for posting the question.

Comment: I think you can do something with `applicationDidBecomeActive`

Comment: @SaadChaudhry hmm, that isn't very much information, especially as I am already doing something in applicationWillEnterForeground:, and have also tried it in applicationWillEnterForeground:

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround but you can always try :

Put a UIImageView on the root view controller. (or create a new one with the splash screen image)
Once the real splash is removed, this view will displayed then you can remove it after with the effect of your choice.

Comment: It is supposed to be show each subsequent time the app opens (press home button, reopen app, press home button, reopen app...).

Comment: precisely with this, you should be able to display the view whenever you want because it's not a real splashscreen . It just a view that you can add & remove.

Comment: Hm, for me it works :/ 
have you tried in the - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application ?

Comment: Yeah, and it does the same as mentioned in my original question.